# Windows Server 2012 R2 4k Resolution

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, windows-server-2012-r2, nvidia-geforce, 4k-resolution

I have recently purchased 4K monitor - using Windows 2012 Server R2 with NVIDIA GeoForce GT 630 graphics card through HDMI port.

Currently, The maximum resolution I am getting is in: Display/Screen Resolution is 1920 x 1080.

I am wondering how can I get 4K (3840*2160)result ?

Comment: Server 2012 is what Windows 8 is derived so, surely, you should be able to install Windows 8 drivers to get the card working with the desired resolution?

Comment: ah, looking at the NVidia website for the GT 630 it doesn't have an entry for "Windows Server"... you may be out of luck... you could *try* the Windows 8 drivers available, but they probably won't work/be supported...